# How to setup svn with auto upload file to var/www

Tags: svn

I am not an expert and i just learning. I tried find out how to do this but i can't find. I create SVN folder in `/var/svn/project1` and i create vhost on dir `/var/www/project1` When i download my project1 on local disk and make some changes i should make commit and on server `svn_update`. After this some files in svn repo `/var/svn/project1` should be updated. But how to make this all project and files available from `/var/www/project1` from browser. It looks like file should be update in svn and auto upload in /var/www ? or only some sym link ? How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a [post-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html). Read [SVNBook | Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks). BTW, there are plenty of hook examples on StackOverflow and on the web.

Comment: But can i make repo in /var/www/project ? and THX for help

Comment: @user4347073 don't confuse a repository and a working copy. You want to place a working copy there, as far as I understand.

Comment: i want create test env and want sync repo after commit to see changes on test live.i will prepare post commit script with svnsync